# Is it bad practice to constantize parameters submitted through the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a single-table-inheritance setup where I have a single Controller (I felt having multiple would be duplicative). However, for some methods, I'd like to call into the subclasses of the models. I figured I could have the browser send a parameter that I'd write a case statement against. Something like:

```
case @model[:type]
when "A"
  @results = Subclass1.search(params[:term])
when "B"
  @results = Subclass2.search(params[:term])
...
end
```

Alternatively though, I learned that Ruby, in all it's trickery can create a model out of a string. Something like:

```
@results = params[:model].constantize.search(params[:term])
```

My question: is this a bad practice? I can imagine someone sneaky could craft a request that would get me to form an arbitrary internal object.. but I could confirm that the object is a subclass of the thing I want..

Comment: What should happen if params[:model] is not one of the expected? results is nil? empty? raise an exception?

Comment: "constantize"? Hmm. I guess I'll googlize it.

Comment: @tokland just getting back to this now.. I'd probably like it to throw an exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When doing this, i like to refactor it with `case`, just to be very clear about my allowed inputs:

```
@results = case params[:model]
  when 'page'   then Page
  when 'post'   then Post
  else raise 'finger'
end.search(params[:term])
```

Comment: I agree with @Rein, in this case a case is overkill, too verbose.

Comment: I guess it's a question of taste. I find that case makes the logic flow very clear, which is good in these cases. The implicit else is handy too, because it is good practice to actually handle the error case as well. Finally, i don't like the idea of instantiating a hash every time the method is called only to use it as a case-style lookup :P But it's a question of taste for sure, and i've used both both.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **whitelist** of objects that you check it against before you do it, then you should be ok. You just always want to make sure you are santizing and validating input coming from external sources very throughly to protect yourself.

Comment: In this case I would just use a hash/map -- which would function *as* the "white-list" *and* explicit type-map. Just because something can be done doesn't mean it should be done ;-)

Comment: @pst. In my answer a propose to use a hash, but I think that @ctcherry's proposal does make a lot of sense when the param string is exactly the class name. You build a whitelist (an array or set) and you constantize only if it's there.

Comment: I might use a whitelist as part of some larger handling construct, whenover the logic is too complex/big to neatly fit into one controller action using case or hash lookup. I wouldn't take that route in a large framework like Rails, because it has a kind of hacky, small-scale nature to it, but it can be useful when dealing with a lot of similar resources and requests, using something like Sinatra.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet uses Ick's `maybe` for simplicity, but write it as you feel comfortable, the point is simply to use a hash:

```
@results = {"A" => Subclass1, "B" => Subclass2}[params[:model]].maybe.search(params[:term])
```

Comment: +1 I'm not a fan of the inline hash (I'd likely use a variable/constant/method), but I do agree with the explicit map (and implicit 'whitelist' there-in)

Comment: @pst. Yes, probably in real code I'd move the hash to a class constant to keep the action code lean and more readable.

Comment: While being slightly more compact (and logically fun), this approach also forces someone reading your code for the first time to lookup the hash constant, and probably "ick" too, after asking around about what that "maybe" statement means. It's also easier to forget handling the error case properly (like rendering a 404).

Comment: @Jostein. Yeah, that's why I asked (in the comments to the question) what should the code do if the param is not a known classname (it's a pity when people does not give feedback for their own questions, sigh). As we don't know, I took the most compact solution (after let it just blow with a nil.search). What's the "hash constant" you are referring to? I didn't get this. Truth is I don't refrain from using Ick, Facets and other cool libraries, it's a way to show them to people.

Comment: @tokland. Sure, there are many solutions. By hash constant i basically mean wherever you keep the hash when it's not in the method body.

Comment: @Jostein: But the hash is there, in the body: {"A" => Subclass1, "B" => Subclass2}. I guess I don't get what you mean.